# Looping through worksheets with multiple for loops and If function inside is not working

Tags: vba, excel

The code works but only applies to the current worksheet. My goal is to apply functioning code to all worksheets by looping through them. This code does not seem to loop.

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Cntains_String_Text_Value()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 200
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PUT" Or Cells(iCntr, 3) = "CALL" Or Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PRN" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next ws
End Sub
```

If I add the ws designation to the "Cells" I get a mismatch error on the "If" line. what is going wrong here?

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Cntains_String_Text_Value()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 200
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PUT" Or ws.Cells(iCntr, 3) = "CALL" Or ws.Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PRN" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd get a type mismatch on that line.  As @Vityata says in his answer - qualify each range with the worksheet (and workbook if need be) that the range belongs to.  Your second set of code checks the `ws` worksheet, but then deletes the row from whichever sheet is active.  Qualifying the rows with `ws.Rows(iCntr)` should solve it, or use a [With...End With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/with-statement) block as Vityata has.

Comment: You could also use _SELECT CASE_ instead of _IF... THEN_:  `Select Case ws.Cells(iCntr, 3): Case "PUT", "CALL", "PRN": ws.Rows(iCntr).Delete: End Select` (NB: Each `:` is a new line) or you could even use `If InStr("PUTCALLPRN", ws.Cells(iCntr, 3)) <> 0 Then` but that would pick up any single letter in a cell that appears in the string.

Comment: I wonder if an error value would cause that.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice always to declare the parent worksheet (and the parent workbook, whenever working with more workbooks):

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Cntains_String_Text_Value()

    On Error GoTo sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Cntains_String_Text_Value_Error

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Dim lRow As Long
            Dim iCntr As Long
            lRow = 200
            For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PUT" Or .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "CALL" Or .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PRN" Then
                    .Rows(iCntr).Delete
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next ws

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Cntains_String_Text_Value_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " on cell " & Cells(iCntr, 3).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Still receive a mismatch arror on the If .Cells line. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @JordyBreuker -  See the values of `.Cells(iCntr,3)` and etc. They could be probably merged or errors?

Comment: The values are either blank (empty), "PUT", "CALL, or "PRN". Moreover, the script works on single sheets when I am not adding the prefix of "ws" before "Cells". It has something to do with the looping, but I cant figure out what.

Comment: @JordyBreuker - start pressing `F8` and see on which line it is happening. Then see the value in that line.

Comment: I just get a run-time error '13': type mismatch on line: 
    If .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PUT" Or .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "CALL" Or .Cells(iCntr, 3) = "PRN" Then

Comment: @JordyBreuker - super. What is the value of `iCntr` when you get the error? What is in the corresponding cell?

Comment: not sure how I can retrieve that info? I use iCntr just to target the 3rd column for all 200 rows.

Comment: @JordyBreuker - run the code again and let me know what you get in the `MsgBox()`.

Comment: That works. I get an error 13 on cell $C$200. this cell is empty because it is out of reach of the datatable (I put in 200 as an arbitrary row nr. since my various worksheets vary in row length)
EDIT: I think I found the problem. There is an output tab in among them as well which I think has an invalid value. I think i just need to start at worksheet nr 7 (or any nr) in order for it to work. Can you help me with how I start from worksheet X and onwards?

Comment: @JordyBreuker - check the `C200` on every worksheet. Probably on what of them it is quite different.

Comment: @vitaya I think I found the problem. There is an output tab in among them as well which I think has an invalid value. I think i just need to start at worksheet nr 7 (or any nr) in order for it to work. Can you help me with how I start from worksheet X and onwards?

Comment: @JordyBreuker - if you remove the whole tab would it work? Concerning ignoring worksheet, you can put `If ws.Name <> "Output" Then` to ignore the worksheet. Concerning starting from the 7. worksheet - it is better to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @vitaya Thank you very much for the help! I think I will be able to fix it from here on out. Definetly will use the error msgbox thing more often to track errors.

Comment: Could you accept the answer please so that Vityata has something to show for his efforts?